# using RegExp constructor result into wrong output

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex expression which i use for email address validation. It is working fine as literal expression but showing different result when using the `RegExp` constructor.

```js
var emailpattern=/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/g;

console.log(emailpattern.test('nithin@gmail.com'))//true

var obj = new RegExp('^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$','g');

console.log(obj.test('nithin@gmail.com'))//false
```

Comment: flagged as duplicate? If i knew it has to be double escaped i would not ask this question at the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove quotes for the pattern which you have specified in the `new RegExp()` to get rid of extra overhead of escaping the `\` character:

```js
var emailpattern=/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/g;

console.log(emailpattern.test('nithin@gmail.com'))//true

var obj = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,'g');

console.log(obj.test('nithin@gmail.com'))//false
```

**Escaping the `\` character:**

```js
var emailpattern=/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/g;

console.log(emailpattern.test('nithin@gmail.com'))//true

var obj = new RegExp('(([^<>()\\[\\]\\\.,;:\s@"]+(\\.[^<>()\\[\\]\\\.,;:\\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))','g');

console.log(obj.test('nithin@gmail.com'))//false
```

Comment: it worked. I removed the quotes and used the regex pattern identifier

Comment: @NithinChandran glad to help. :)